# Change desktop background image in Cinnamon 2.8.6

Tags: 14.04, cinnamon

I am using Cinnamon 2.8.6 and ubuntu 16.04.
I need to set specific image as desktop background.
However after google search, I got solution with following commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/techy/Downloads/desktop_bg.jpg 
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
```

After this, background is changed. But I am not able to understand which package is responsible to execute this change ? How the script is actually working ? Is there any other way to do it from terminal ?

Comment: All of these are (among other) shell commands so *this is* a way to do it from terminal (and imho the most elegant one). What "other" way are you looking for? Also `org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons` is not related to the desktop background wallpaper.

Comment: I want to know which script is responsible to load the background image after reboot. Is there any documentation like, how cinnamon or gnome desktop managers interact with ubuntu files to change the desktop wallpaper ?

Answer (score 3):

To understand what these commands do let's follow the thread.

1. `man gsettings` says

   > GSettings configuration tool

   but what is "GSettings"?
2. On https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/GSettings I found:

   > GSettings are a nice way to manage your application’s settings.

   Ok, that's a little better because it describes the high-level purpose but it's still very vague.
3. Let's go back to `man gsettings`. The usage of the `gsettings set` command is described like this:

   > `gsettings set SCHEMA [:PATH]  KEY VALUE`

   So GSettings appears to be some kind of key-value store with hierarchical key schemata.

   To summarize, the command

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/techy/Downloads/desktop_bg.jpg
   ```

   will assign the value `file:///home/techy/Downloads/desktop_bg.jpg` to the key `picture-uri` belonging to the schema `org.gnome.desktop.background`.
4. Now what happens when that value is (re-)assigned? Here's another `gsettings` command:

   > `monitor SCHEMA [:PATH]  [KEY]`
   >
   > Monitors `KEY` for changes and prints the changed values. If no `KEY` is specified, all keys in the schema are monitored. Monitoring will continue until the process is terminated.

   So applications can monitor schemata and keys for changes.

   Apparently the process responsible for drawing the desktop background wallpaper monitors this key and reacts to changes by drawing the image in the file referenced in the `picture-uri` value. Usually the desktop compositor of your desktop environment is responsible for that. In your case that would be Cinnamon but other people might have Gnome Shell or MATE or Unity.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
Can you give reference to some documentation about the error:

(process:15247): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/866195/ubuntu-gnome-desktop-change-wallpaper 

created new question.