# ubuntu-gnome-desktop change wallpaper

Tags: dbus, gsettings

I have installed `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` from configuration file (Ubuntu 16.04).
Then I am executing

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/techy/Downloads/desktop_bg.jpg
```

and the error generated is

```
*error*: **(process:15247): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY**
```

Can someone provide me reference how can I solve it? I am trying to set specific image as desktop background.

Comment: Why do you need to set it that way? If you are coding script for auto-changing wallapers, there's already nice app for this, called **Wallch**.

Comment: I am looking to do it using a script.

Comment: Wallch also got CLI, maybe it will meet your needs, `wallch --change=/home/techy/Downloads`

Comment: From which environment are you executing `gsettings`? I assume it's from a cron script or some background service because there's no D-Bus session daemon (which you need for GSettings) or X server (which would allow you to start a new D-Bus session daemon) available. What are you trying to achieve ultimately?

Comment: I am executing from shell script. My script should change the desktop background.

Comment: @GreggD- wallch is not working.

Comment: I am getting this error now. 

'(process:16010): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=933ae0d31fab40fe95872ec177c616c5 --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1'

Comment: are you still having this problem?